# How to set the z index of a view to be in front of a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Say I have a main view that looks like

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <CustomView></CustomView>
  <TextView></TextView>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/clickable_layout">
  </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Say I spawn a new fragment which has a new view that covers half the screen and does not cover relative layout "clickable_layout". If the behavior of "clickable_layout" is that it expands to fill the height of the screen on click, is there anyway for me to have it expand over the existing fragment and its view?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, sibling views that are added to the parent later will appear on top of their predecessors. If your clickable_layout keeps on being the last in it's parent, it will show up on top of all the others.

You would need to make sure that you insert the fragment to a container that is a child of your root RelativeLayout and also appears before clickable_layout